# CSS code organizing

Tags: html, css, html5

I like to keep my code organized, usually in several files. It is good for CSS.
For instance:

I have three files:

- First - `layout.html`, this is the main template.
- Second - `grid.css` is style sheet where I decribe position of all elements.
- Third - `style.css` is where I describe appearence of elements.

Listings:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--layout.html-->
<html>
    <head>
    <title>The best title ever</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css" type="text/css"/>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--The top part of site -->
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>

    <!--The main part of site, where al information is-->
    <div id="main">
        <!--Container with floating tabs. -->
        <ul id="tabs">
        <!--Floating tabs-->
        <li id="tab1">Tab 1</li>
        <li id="tab2">Tab 2</li>
        <li id="tab3">Tab 3</li>
        </ul>
        <!--Container where we see content of ACTIVE tab-->
        <div id="content">
        Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--The bottom part of site -->
    <div id="footer">
        Footer.
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

grid.css

```
/*
  Rules for three base blocks.
  */
#header,#main,#footer{
    width:990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    }

/*
  Rules for tabs.
  */
#tabs{
    diplay:block;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#tabs li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:330px;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid silver;/*Uncomment it for debugging */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;

    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
/*
  Rules for content block.
  */
#content{
    width:990px;
    height:700px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid silver;/*Uncomment it for debugging */
}
```

style.css

```
body{
    background-color:silver;
    /*And all things like that, colors,fonts,etc..*/
}
```

What do you think of this code organization?

How do you organize your style sheets?

Comment: This question seems a little off topic for CR:  [your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  Proper code organization *always* makes sense, but how I organize code might not make sense for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my directory structure:

```
./
  app/
  theme/
```

Here is my CSS build script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Directory to write the minified CSS files.
OUTPUT_DIR=../css

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR/app

lessc -x ui.less > $OUTPUT_DIR/ui.css

# Create minified CSS files for the applications.
for i in app/*; do
  lessc -x $i > $OUTPUT_DIR/app/$(basename $i .less).css
done
```

Here are the main files I use (relatively located in `./`):

```
colour.less
constant.less
fieldset.less
font.less
layout.less
sprite.less
master.less
```

Each `.less` file under the `app/` directory contains overrides for any of the above styles. The `theme/` directory contains constants for colour themes. For example:

```
@header-nav-search : #1abc9c;
@header-nav-book   : #e67e22;
@header-nav-account: #e74c3c;
```

The `master.less` file ropes them all together:

```
@import "constant.less";
@import "fieldset.less";
@import "layout.less";
@import "font.less";
@import "colour.less";
```

Each app-specific file starts with a reference to the theme:

```
@import "../theme/peaceful.less";
```

I welcome improvements. The short answer is: use [LESSCSS](http://lesscss.org/) or an equivalent language that compiles into CSS. Having variables and functions to use for generating CSS is extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using multiple CSS files is a common practice. And since they're CSS files, the files don't take long for the browser to render.

You can use the `@import` CSS rule to 'sew' them all together, if you wish, but I tend to just leave them.

Often, I use four CSS files together;

- `reset.css` - reset all user agents
- `default.css` - modern browsers
- `ui.css` - I personally like to keep the user interface aesthetics separate
- `mobile.css` - an easy way to alter the page for mobile devices, without having to maintain two versions of your website. This is inserted in via CSS `@media` queries.

And if older versions of Internet Explorer need separate CSS, they can be given using IE conditional comments. For example;

**If you want to target stale browsers like IE8 and below, you can use this:**

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
```

**And for more modern browsers that include *decent* HTML5 and CSS3 support, you can target IE9 and above, plus browsers that are not IE, with this:**

```
<!--[if gte IE 9|!IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

That's my usual setup.